# How to see bitrise build result from vsts

Tags: xamarin, azure-devops, bitrise

So I'm starting a Xamarin IOS build on bitrise on every pull request made to my branch, but I want to be able to get status on that build and display it in Visual Studio Team Services.

How do I do that ? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the project you build on bitrise is not located on VSTS git repo, it can’t be displayed in VSTS.
- If the project you build on bitrise is located on VSTS git repo, you can use **web hook** to trigger bitrise build when pull request is made, and view the build result on VSTS. Detail steps as below:

  **1.   Get webhook URL**

  Bitrise app page -> Code tab -> select visual studio online for webhooks -> copy the webhook URL.
  [image]

  **2.   Add a web hook in VSTS**

  In VSTS team project -> Service Hooks tab -> create a new subscription -> select web Hooks -> Next -> select  **Pull request created** for this type of event -> specify repo and target branch -> Next -> paste the webhook URL  as URL -> Test -> make sure it can work -> Finish.

  **3.   View bitrise build reults**

  In VSTS Service Hooks page, you can view the build status directly. 
   [image]

  To view the details, you can check in History.

  [image]

Comment: Just a note, if the build's end result have to be reported back to VSTS that is not supported out of the box by bitrise.io right now. The status you highlighted only indicates whether the build was started, not that it finished with success. To send back the build's final status (success/error) you can create a step, similar to the existing **GitHub Status** step (https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-github-status/blob/master/step.yml), or create a feature request (https://discuss.bitrise.io/c/feature-request) for a built in option.

Comment: @ViktorBenei is the reporting back to VSTS still not supported?